# Laravel Cashier-Stripe retreive receipt for one time payment

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm discovering Laravel (v10) Cashier (v14) to use **Stripe one time payment** with `checkoutCharge()`.

When coming back from a successful payment we only get the `CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID`, but Cashier seems to not provide a receipt access from this checkout session id.

The only solution I've found is to call `$user->invoices()->first()` in the checkout success callback Controller. This call will return a `Stripe\Invoice` Collection for a period of time.

Is there another way to retrieve the receipt url from a checkout session id ?

Thanks & cheers